# Is it possible to send a Facebook request without a dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dialog

I need to send a request to a user using my custom dialog (which user has other options). After this, I have 'users_ids' to send requests.

Is it possible do this using [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)?

(I did not find any way to do this at *[Requests Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of requests as mentioned in the [Social Channels](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/) documentation (section Requests): User-generated and App-generated.

You can send App-generated requests to the user both from the server and client side with out the need of using a dialog.
How ever you can send these requests only for a user who authorized your app, as it described in the [connection in the user object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests).

The User-generated requests can only be sent using the dialogs, as the name implies.

The best source for this issue is the [Requests documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/).